# When trying to use Azure DevOps Pipelines Azure CLI task az container exec the shell outputs errors

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

```
az container exec --resource-group myRG --name myImageName --exec-command "/bin/bash"
```

This error message is thrown:

```
 [command]/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/azureclitaskscript1588671209398.sh
 The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
 
 (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 215, in invoke
     cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 625, in execute
     raise ex
   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 689, in _run_jobs_serially
     results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 682, in _run_job
     six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
     raise value
   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 659, in _run_job
     result = cmd_copy(params)
   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 324, in __call__
     return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 531, in default_command_handler
     return op(**command_args)
   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/container/custom.py", line 621, in container_exec
     _start_exec_pipe(execContainerResponse.web_socket_uri, execContainerResponse.password)
   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/container/custom.py", line 655, in _start_exec_pipe
     oldtty = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
 termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

To open an issue, please run: 'az feedback'

Comment: maybe you need to explain what you are trying to do or want to do,

Comment: I am trying to execute a command inside a azure container instance

az container exec --resource-group myRG --name myImageName --exec-command "/bin/bash".  This command is working in windows agent but not working in Linux agent. See the above error got from azure cli task

Comment: Is it MS Hosted agent or self-hosted agent ? Also which version of CLI are you using. When you said it is working on windows and not on linux, could you please share the vm type / name if it is MS hosted agent.

Comment: Microsoft hosted agent: ubuntu 20.0

Comment: Share your pipeline

Comment: Please have a check with Microsoft-hosted: Ubuntu-18.04 agent. As per the different softwares preinstalled on the agent(doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software)), Ubuntu 18.04 has "Azure CLI (azure-cli) 2.38.0" same as windows agent. In addition, the command `az container exec` is to open an interactive bash shell, could you please double confirm it's working with windows agent for pipeline? It's recommended to raise a new ticket for the agent issue in link: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues

Comment: There was an issue for this, but closed without fix - https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13352.